# React Native dynamically changing image width and height causes flickering issues

Tags: react-native

I am trying to map the images to different views and render them. They render fine until I hit an array that has multiple images(my console log keeps looping) through the images. Im not entirely sure what is happening and the images flicker up and down due to the looping. Its works fine when there is only one image.

```
imageContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      width: screenWidth - 5,
      height: imgHeight, //if used with Image.getSize, look before on where that is referenced. 
    },
    image: {
      flex: 1,
      width: undefined,
      height: undefined,
      resizeMode: "contain",
    },
```

My View:

```
{item.imageLinks.map(imgLink => {
            Image.getSize(imgLink, (width, height) => {
              console.log('image Width and Height', width, height)
              setImgHeight(height)
            });
            return <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
              <Image
                style={styles.image}
                resizeMethod="scale"
                source={{ uri: imgLink }}
              />
            </View>
```

Comment: you are using single `imgHeight` for all images. So it will cause your problem. It's better if you could write your own `Image` component then render it on the loop

Comment: I will try that and provide an update. Thank you.